# Understanding jQuery each loop

Tags: jquery, each

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="sectionInner"><div class="carousel"></div></div>
<div class="sectionInner"></div>
<div class="sectionInner"></div>
<div class="sectionInner"></div>
```

JS:

```
function checkForCarousel() {
    $('.sectionInner').each(function(i) {
        if($(this).has('.carousel')) {
            alert('We got a Carousel!');
        }
        else {
            alert('No Carousels here')
        }
    });
}

checkForCarousel();
```

What I am trying to do is loop over the four div.sectionInner if I find a child with class of carousel then I want to append some buttons. I know I can just target the carousel directly but this is part of a bigger picture and I do have a reason for wanting to use a loop.

Anyway as the loop begins it alerts 'We got a Carousel' as you'd expect for the first div. It then carries on alerting 'We got a Carousel' when quite clearly we don't have Carousels for the other three divs. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you're testing for the existence of a jQuery object, which is always `true`. You need to test for `length > 0` instead:

```
if($(this).has('.carousel').length) { // is false if length == 0
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/DzafK/

Answer (score 3):

This is the classic case of "truthy" and "falsey" values in javascript. You will notice that $(this).has('.carousel') will return an object. Objects are always truthy in javascript. Please refer the following link:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.sectionInner').each(function(i) {
    if ($('div', this).hasClass('carousel')) {
        alert('We got a Carousel!');
    }
    else {
        alert('No Carousels here')
    }
});
```